# avcodec_decode_audio4 decoded data different on device and simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, xcode5

I'm having issues where the decoded audio sounds punchy/garbled simply can't tell what is being heard when decoded on an iPhone/iPad device. However, when decoding the audio on simulator the audio is perfect.

I do realize emulator runs on a different CPU architecture i386 while actual device is ARMv7 so the issue could be something around that.

I have printed the compressed data on device and simulator before being decoded and it matches. Then I printed the decoded data for device and simulator and they are different. That leads me to think something is happening with the decoder. I can see that it is not a byte swap issue since the data is just completely different.

Any ideas on what I could or look into? I don't have this issue on Android...

First decoded audio frame.

***DEVICE:***

```
0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0xda, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
```

***EMULATOR:***

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
```

---

**UPDATE 1**
I was able to resolve the issue by disabling asm with `--disable-asm`. Something must not be working correctly with the ARM asm files.